# Can't get an Image overlapping a form

Tags: html, css, image, forms, overlap

Hi i'm kinda new in frontend and i've found a lot of answers on this site! Now i've crossed a problem and i can't find a solution. I would like to have an image (pooh bear) with a little overlap on a form.

I have tried to put it in the form div and in the content div, that is not working. Now it just pushes the form down.

jsfiddle.net/Marcelle/2mj3czLk/embedded/result/

And i'm trying to get it like this https://lhlp.nl/test/images/idea.png

Can anyone tell he how to fix this? :) Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, i had some overload while trying to explain it all in proper English and getting some link in for the code. I'll make sure it's right the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#fixedimage {
      margin:500px 0 -100 1480px;
    display:block;   
    position: absolute;//MODIFICATION
    padding-left:600px; //MODIFICATION
}
#content {
width: 400px;
margin: -10px 400px 30px 5%;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #ffd200;
border-radius: 10px;
float: right;
position:inherit;
}
```

this is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mj3czLk/5/)

Comment: This worked! I replaced the margin for just a margin-top and now it's where it needs te be! Thank you so much :)

Comment: if this answer helped,mark this answer as accepted :) (Y)

Comment: but here the image is still independent from the content div - I suppose it should be attached to it when it's moving... (see my solution below)

Answer (score 0):

to put a div partly on top of another div without affecting its contents, but still attached to it (= moving along if the content div changes position), the main "ingredients" are:

- put the form div *inside* the content div
- `position: relative;` on the content div
- `position: absolute;` on the form div, with `top` *or* `bottom` and
  `left` *or* `right` settings as desired (determines the offset or overlap)

EDIT / ADDITION: Here`s a fork of your fiddle that contains all this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3op51apx/

...and its most important CSS:

```
#fixedimage {
      margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -220px;
    right: 0px;
}

#content {

    width: 400px;
    margin: 250px 0 0 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffd200;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
```

and the slightly changed HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<img id="fixedimage" src="https://lhlp.nl/test/images/poe.png" >
    <h1 class="start">JA,</h1>
etc. etc.
```

Comment: @Marcelle  This really works the way you asked (the bear overlaps the form container, is attached to the form container and moves _with_ _it_ when the form itself dynamically moves). Have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

see the codepen demo for you

```css
#fixedimage {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -150px;
    bottom:0px;
}

#content {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #ffd200;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position:relative;
}

 
 label {
  margin: -20px 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: block;
 }

 form {
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
 }

  form div {
   padding: 3px 0;
   clear: both;
  }

 input.text {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 14px);
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
  height: 24px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 }
 
 input.mini { 
   width: -webkit-calc(17% - 11px);
   width: calc(17% - 11px);
  }

  input.small { 
   width: -webkit-calc(40% - 14px);
   width: calc(40% - 14px);
  }

  input.medium { 
   width: -webkit-calc(60% - 20px);
   width: calc(60% - 20px);
  }

  div input:nth-child(2) {
   margin-left: 6px;
  }

 select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 }

  select.day {
   width: -webkit-calc(25% - 6px);
   width: calc(25% - 6px);
   margin-right: 6px;
  } 
  
  select.month {
   width: -webkit-calc(45% - 6px);
   width: calc(45% - 6px);
   margin-right: 6px;
  }

  select.year {
   width: 30%;
  }

 input.submit {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #e55a00;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0bbf14 0%, #0e9215 50%, #106c15 80%);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
```

```html
<body>



    
<div id="content">
<img id="fixedimage" src="https://lhlp.nl/test/images/poe.png" />
 <h1 class="start">JA,</h1>
    <p class="start">ik wil boeken</p>
    
 <form id="form" method="post" action="#form">
  
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Voornaam kind" class="text" />  </div>

<div><select name="gender kid" class="gender"><option value="1">Kind</option><option value="2">Meisje</option><option value="3">Jongen</option></select></div>            

  <div>
   <select name="day" class="day"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select><select name="month" class="month"><option value="1">januari</option><option value="2">februari</option><option value="3">maart</option><option value="4">april</option><option value="5">mei</option><option value="6">juni</option><option value="7">juli</option><option value="8">augustus</option><option value="9">september</option><option value="10">oktober</option><option value="11">november</option><option value="12">december</option></select><select name="year" class="year"><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1930">1930</option></select>  </div>
            
            <div><select name="gender" class="gender"><option value="1">Aanhef</option><option value="2">Mevrouw</option><option value="3">De heer</option></select></div> 
            
        <div>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Voornaam" class="text medium" /><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Achternaam" class="text small" />  </div>
           
           <div>
   <input type="text" name="postalcode" placeholder="Postnummer" class="text small" /><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Huisnr" class="text mini" /><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Toev." class="text small" />  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="text medium" /><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="text small" />  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="iban" name="iban" placeholder="IBAN" class="text" />  </div>
            
            
            <p class="small"><a href=""> Bereken hier je IBAN.</a></p>
            
            <p class="small">Ik ga akkoord met de <a href="#" onClick="window.open('terms.html','terms','toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=600,height=400'); return false;">actievoorwaarden</a> en ontvang de 4 kinderboeken vrijblijvend.</p>


  <div>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Direct profiteren &raquo;" class="submit" />  </div>

 </form>
    
    
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Tnx for your solutionMohamed! This also works great only the placement was to high on the form and can't get it down. But the code was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```css
#content {
 width: 400px;
 margin:auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #ffd200;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position:relative;
}

 
 label {
  margin: -20px 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: block;
 }

 form {
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
 }

  form div {
   padding: 3px 0;
   clear: both;
  }

 input.text {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 14px);
  width: calc(100% - 14px);
  height: 24px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 }
 
 input.mini { 
   width: -webkit-calc(17% - 11px);
   width: calc(17% - 11px);
  }

  input.small { 
   width: -webkit-calc(40% - 14px);
   width: calc(40% - 14px);
  }

  input.medium { 
   width: -webkit-calc(60% - 20px);
   width: calc(60% - 20px);
  }

  div input:nth-child(2) {
   margin-left: 6px;
  }

 select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 }

  select.day {
   width: -webkit-calc(25% - 6px);
   width: calc(25% - 6px);
   margin-right: 6px;
  } 
  
  select.month {
   width: -webkit-calc(45% - 6px);
   width: calc(45% - 6px);
   margin-right: 6px;
  }

  select.year {
   width: 30%;
  }

 input.submit {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #e55a00;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0bbf14 0%, #0e9215 50%, #106c15 80%);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
.poo-bear{
 background:url(https://lhlp.nl/test/images/poe.png) no-repeat right bottom;
 width:200px;
 height:346px;
 position:absolute; right:-150px;
 bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <div class="poo-bear"></div>
 <h1 class="start">JA,</h1>
    <p class="start">ik wil boeken</p>
    
 <form id="form" method="post" action="#form">
  
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Voornaam kind" class="text" />  </div>

<div><select name="gender kid" class="gender"><option value="1">Kind</option><option value="2">Meisje</option><option value="3">Jongen</option></select></div>            

  <div>
   <select name="day" class="day"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select><select name="month" class="month"><option value="1">januari</option><option value="2">februari</option><option value="3">maart</option><option value="4">april</option><option value="5">mei</option><option value="6">juni</option><option value="7">juli</option><option value="8">augustus</option><option value="9">september</option><option value="10">oktober</option><option value="11">november</option><option value="12">december</option></select><select name="year" class="year"><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1930">1930</option></select>  </div>
            
            <div><select name="gender" class="gender"><option value="1">Aanhef</option><option value="2">Mevrouw</option><option value="3">De heer</option></select></div> 
            
        <div>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Voornaam" class="text medium" /><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Achternaam" class="text small" />  </div>
           
           <div>
   <input type="text" name="postalcode" placeholder="Postnummer" class="text small" /><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Huisnr" class="text mini" /><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Toev." class="text small" />  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="text medium" /><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="text small" />  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="iban" name="iban" placeholder="IBAN" class="text" />  </div>
            
            
            <p class="small"><a href=""> Bereken hier je IBAN.</a></p>
            
            <p class="small">Ik ga akkoord met de <a href="#" onClick="window.open('terms.html','terms','toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=600,height=400'); return false;">actievoorwaarden</a> en ontvang de 4 kinderboeken vrijblijvend.</p>


  <div>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Direct profiteren &raquo;" class="submit" />  </div>

 </form>
    
    
    
</div>
```